# ValueError("empty pattern") in file monitor with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, monitor, pathlib

I monitor with python directory to get an alert when file created.

Sometimes I get an exception while file created in this folder:

```
File .....watchdog\utils\patterns.py , line 30 in <genexpr>
   return (any(path(match(p) for p in include_patterns)
File"c:\python3\lib\pathlib.py", line 921, in match
raise ValueError("empty pattern")
ValueError: empty pattern
```

This is the code in python .

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

def on_created(event):
    with open(event.src_path,'r') as f:
        data=f.read()
    print(data)
    print(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been created!")

def on_deleted(event):
    print(f"what the f**k! Someone deleted {event.src_path}!")

def on_modified(event):
    print(f"hey buddy, {event.src_path} has been modified")

def on_moved(event):
    print(f"ok ok ok, someone moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = "*.csv"
    ignore_patterns = ""
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

    my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
    my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved
    path = "t/"
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)
    my_observer.start()
    time.sleep(10)
```

How do I fix the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in lists of patterns, not a single string. And `None`, not an empty string.

```
my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(
    patterns=["*"],
    ignore_patterns=None,  # pass in `None` in case of no ignores
    ignore_directories=False,
    case_sensitive=True,
)
```

Comment: but sometimes it work and sometimes not , are you sure that is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the problem?

Comment: this fixed my problem. By the way, "sometimes it works", is a big problem!!!